# OS X cannot reinstall boot2docker : Error requesting socket: exit status 255

Tags: osx-yosemite, boot2docker

I reinstalled boot2docker on my OS X computer.  Running `boot2docker up`, I get an error message:

```
boot2docker up
Waiting for VM and Docker daemon to start...   
..............................................         
ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
Started.
Trying to get Docker socket one more time
Error requesting socket: exit status 255
Auto detection of the VM's Docker socket failed.
Please run `boot2docker -v up` to diagnose.
```

Running verbose (`boot2docker -v up`), I can see all the tries:

```
executing: /usr/bin/ssh ssh -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -o   
StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o  
LogLevel=quiet -p 2022 -i /Users/baboo/.ssh/id_boot2docker
docker@localhost grep tcp:// /proc/$(cat /var/run/docker.pid)/cmdline
Error requesting socket: exit status 255
```

I already have in my `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

What's the meaning of this error and how can I solve it?

Comment: Did you add the broadcast host entry to /etc/hosts? Usually the broadcast host is the same subnet as the host with 255 as the last octet. (Ie if your machine was 192.168.1.101, your broadcast would be 192.168.1.255). Try removing that entry. The broadcast address should be specified elsewhere in the network config without it needing to be in /etc/hosts.

Comment: no it's the standard Yosemite /etc/hosts

Comment: Well you can check sshd_config that it's listening on port 2022.. that's the "-p 2022"...

Comment: I deleted and re-added my /etc/hosts  file... ( maybe corrupted) and I also reset all the permissions in my ~/  user folder... ( maybe corrupted) then I uninstalled VirtualBox , boot2docker, ( and also Vagrant unused somewhere... so cleaning all virtual machine related tuff .. then I reinstalled the latest Kitematic version ... and  and it's now up and running well....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an issues page on GH with the same error message -- they said that they had a stray VirtualBox bootdocker vm... you can see the article here:

[Link to GitHub issue](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/issues/625)

They basically deleted the Virtualbox VM and re-inited.
Hopefully that works for you.

Comment: yes, as Kinematic is now part of Dockergroup, the latest Kinematic package installs   the latest virtialbox version,  Docker-machine , Docker and create a new VM called dev  ( not bootlicker-vm anymore ..)    Kinematic  GUI s in infancy , so I'm using the CLI....